# Sbt test file cannot find value from src file

Tags: scala, import, build, sbt, scalatest

My sbt project with scala-test is layout as standard:

```
sbt-example
    build.sbt
    src/main/scala/local/search/BinarySearch.scala
    src/main/scala/local/util/Utility.scala
    src/test/scala/local/search/SearchingSuite.scala
```

My build.sbt is very simple:

```
name := "helloworld"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4"
)
```

My BinarySearch.scala looks like:

```
package local.search

object BinarySearch {
    // def ...
}
```

My SearchingSuite.scala looks like:

```
package local.search

import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class SearchingSuite extends FunSuite{
    // call functions from BinarySearch object
}
```

Run commands are:

```
sbt compile
sbt "test-only local.search.SearchingSuite"
```

Then sbt raises error:

```
not found: value BinarySearch
```

What's wrong with my code? And if I need to use some object from Utility.scala, how to import in SearchingSuite.scala?

Thanks, will vote up with any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you are working on class A; and class A requires class B. As long as A and B belong to two different packages, you have to import class B.

In your case, SearchingSuite and BinarySearch belong to two different packages. In particular, the former belongs to the *main* source package, the latter belong to the *test* source package. Therefore, you must import BinarySearch in SearchingSuite. Otherwise, there will be an compilation error like what you have encountered.

To use some object from Utility, you

**import local.util.Utility**

if Utility is a class, or

**import local.util.Utility._**

if Utility is an object.

If you are using some IDE, like Intellij or Eclipse, right click on the error highlight, the IDE will pop up some suggestions.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I just add "import local.search.BinarySearch" in test file, it says "object BinarySearch is not a member of package local.search". I guess I need to use full package name? What is full package name?

Comment: You should push your code to github so that it is easier for us to take a look and help you.

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured out. The object BinarySearch is declared in same package with SearchingSuite, so no need of import is needed. The error is from sbt's weird behaviour: sometime if you do not completely delete files (put them inside recycle bin is not "complete"), sbt is still looking into that "ghost" files. My project is in https://github.com/jz33/Spark-Standalone-Mllib-Test-Suites